# visual studio for Mac unity execution failed

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, visual-studio-mac

I am running the latest version of Visual Studio and the latest version of unity. When I open the project using Visual Studio for Mac, I am able to rebuild the app.

But, when I try to start debugging, I am getting `Execution Failed` without any explanation or build output.

I am able to run the app successfully on iOS through Xcode, although the iPad is refusing to start the app automatically and I have to open it manually.

The issue is that , I can't start the app on Visual Studio for Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, If you open multiple instances of Unity, Visual Studio for Mac will get confused and will not know which project to attach to.

Having one instance solved the issue for me.